# Tensorflow how to dump the result placement algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow

1. I'm curious of model parallelism, and I've read the code from [Yaroslav Bulatov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42081222/8426713). And in that example, we should partition our model (or in tensorflow we called Graph) manually to different partition (left_network & right_network).
   So, I was wondering if I have to make partitions manually, what's the `simple_placer.cc` and `graph_partition.cc` have done to the whole graph? And I'm still not clear as all.
2. In my thought(let me know if anythong wrong):
   If the graph has 8 partitions(subgraph) which can be seen as 8 jobs, and 4 workers,How the partitions distributed to workers can be done through:

- explicit annotations via `tf.device()`, or
- distributed training, `tf.train.replica_device_setter()`

> share the variables across parameter servers, and otherwise put all
> ops on the worker device

But how's the graph make partitions?
I want to trace what's the subgraph (op-nodes set) looks like?
Can I dump the result or I need to trace/modified which code file?

Please let me know if any concepts is wrong or vague.
I'm a rookie of these, any opinion is appreciated.

3. In the code below, is `matmul` a op-node, would it be partition into
   different jobs?

   ```
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    y = tf.matmul(x, W)  + b
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result of the placement algorithm by passing additional options when you call `tf.Session.run()`

```
# ...
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

sess = tf.Session()
options = tf.RunOptions(output_partition_graphs=True)
metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

sess.run(y, options=options, run_metadata=metadata)

# `metadata` now contains information about what happened during the `run()` call.
for partition in metadata.partition_graphs:

  # `partition` is a `tf.GraphDef` representing all the nodes that ran on a single
  # device. All nodes in `partition` have the same `device` value.
  device = partition.node[0].device

  for node in partition.node:
    # e.g. print each node or store it in a dictionary for further analysis.
    # ...
```

Comment: very helpful code snippet. I still wondering is there a way to dump out the graph as PB after Send/Recv OPs inserted?