# Example of tf.Estimator with model parallel execution

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, parallel-processing, deep-learning, distributed-computing

I am currently experimenting with distributed tensorflow.
I am using the `tf.estimator.Estimator` class  (custom model function) together with `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` and managed it to get a working data parallel execution.

However, I would now like to try model parallel execution. I was not able to find any example for that, except [Implementation of model parallelism in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42069147/implementation-of-model-parallelism-in-tensorflow). 
But I am not sure how to implement this using `tf.estimators` (e.g. how to deal with the input functions?).

Does anybody have any experience with it or can provide a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, you should stop using [`tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Estimator) in favor of [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), because `contrib` is [an experimental module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47247622/712995), and classes that have graduated to the core API (such es `Estimator`) automatically get deprecated.

Now, back to your main question, you can create a distributed model and pass it via `model_fn` parameter of [`tf.estimator.Estimator.__init__`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#__init__).

```py
def my_model(features, labels, mode):
  net = features[X_FEATURE]
  with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):
    for units in [10, 20, 10]:
      net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
      net = tf.layers.dropout(net, rate=0.1)

  with tf.device('/device:GPU:2'):
    logits = tf.layers.dense(net, 3, activation=None)
    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 3, 1, 0)
    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, 
                                           logits=logits)

  optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
  train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

[...]

classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=my_model)
```

The model above defines 6 layers with `/device:GPU:1` placement and 3 other layers with `/device:GPU:2` placement. The return value of `my_model` function should be an [`EstimatorSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec) instance. A complete working example can be found in [tensorflow examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/multiple_gpu.py).

Comment: Thanks! I am already using `tf.estimator.Estimator`. Just the `Experiment` class is from `tf.contrib.learn`, but to my knowledge there is no other version of this class.

Also thanks for your example! I think I got it now. I just was not sure how to deal with the input fn etc, but apparently I do not have to do that device specific.

Comment: Right, `Experiment` class is still experimental (sounds funny), that's why it's in `contrib`. This means it's API can change. But once it or any other class is graduated to core, the code should be migrated to core API.